# Java jdbc how to insert current date but formatted into database

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am using postgres 9.4(Date Column) as my database and would like to know if it is possible to insert a formatted date into the database using JDBC preparedstatement in the following format (I been searching around and couldn't find anything): **Aug-21-2015**. This is my code

```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    java.util.Date today = calendar.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    java.util.Date mydate= formatter.parse(today.toString());
    preparedStatement.setDate(2,new java.sql.Date(mydate.getTime()));
```

needless to say that does not work and I get this error

**Unparseable date: "Fri Aug 21 01:17:59 EDT 2015"**
again I am trying to get this into Aug-21-2015 , I can successfully execute the code if I only insert like this

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    java.util.Date mydate = calendar.getTime();
    preparedStatement.setDate(2,new java.sql.Date(mydate.getTime()));
```

but it is inserted as 8-21-2015, I was thinking of maybe just saving it as 8-21-2015 format and then just parsing all of them but would prefer the 1st option.

Comment: Dates do not have "a format". Any format you _see_ when displaying data is applied by the application (e.g. the SQL client) that is displaying that date to you. There is no need to format an instance of `java.sql.Date` before passing it to a `PreparedStatement`. `preparedStatement.setDate(calendar.getTime())` is all you need.

Comment: Don't do that. Format it when you `SELECT` it back out of the database, if you want a specific format. Or format it from Java when you print it to the user from the `java.util.Date` object.

Answer (score 0):

Your date pattern is wrong: it must be:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

For mor information see the [javadoc of SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

A value in a date column itself is not formatted, it is just a date, if you want to format the date when you're reading it back out of the database, just use one of the [date formatting functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html).

E.g.

```
select to_char(your_date_column, 'MON-DD-YYYY') from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you're converting to string and back, but `today.toString()` is **NOT** generating a text string that matches `MM-dd-yyyy`, so `formatter.parse(today.toString())` will fail.

If the intent was to remove the time portion, in order to get "today", you can:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int year  = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day   = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
cal.clear();
cal.set(year, month, day);
java.sql.Date today = new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Or, with Java 8:

```
java.sql.Date today = java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now());
```

**Date Format**

And for your desire the insert a "formatted date", then you are confused. A date column in the database doesn't have a format, it simply stores the date value.

When you query the date column, you get the date value, which can be retrieved in Java using the `ResultSet.getDate()` method.

When you query the date in a tool, the tool will convert the date to a text value for display. Some tools will allow you to control the date format.

If you otherwise want to control the date format, **you** can convert the date to a text column in the query, using DBMS specific formatting functions.

Comment: No need to remove the time "manually". `java.sql.Date` will already do that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Actually, no. The java.sql.Date constructor is `public Date(long date) { super(date); }`. The millis are **not** truncated to a date-only value. Now, the JDBC driver *might* do that, but if you call `setDate()` using a sql.Date into a column that can store date/time, it's really undefined whether the time portion will make it through. Of course, if the column is date-only, you could use `setTimestamp` and you'd only get a date, but using a sql.Date does not in itself guarantee date-only.

Comment: [From the Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) "*To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the particular time zone with which the instance is associated*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The javadoc may say that, but the implementation doesn't do it.

Comment: Which implementation? If a driver doesn't do that (and I haven't seen one that doesn't. The Postgres driver _does_ comply with that) then the driver clearly doesn't comply with the JDBC spec (plus: if it's really a `DATE` column then the DBMS will "truncate" the time part anyway)

Comment: Oh ok thanks for explaining, that cleared up my confusion. I will format the data on Select. I will also read those docs.